# Change document-wide interletter, interword and interline spacing

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, letterspacing, accessibility

According to the 2012 paper [Extra-large letter spacing improves reading in dyslexia](http://college.dargent.free.fr/IMG/pdf/PNAS-Dyslexie-lettres-espacees-full.pdf), some spacing adjustments could make reading easier for dyslexic people, namely

- Add 2.5pt to interletter space
- 3 spaces between words
- double interline spacing

I am looking for a way to set this document-wide. I have found some packages that provide environments to change each of these spacings independently, but it might be bit tedious to wrap everything in three environments, and I don't know how that would work with figure captions, section titles…

Comment: This answers part of the question: [Enlarging tracking (= letter spacing)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/enlarging-tracking-letter-spacing)

Answer (score 6):

With inspiration from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62353/8547) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/820/8547) I have found that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{LetterSpace=25, WordSpace={3}}
\setmainfont{OpenDyslexic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
    […]
\end{document}
```

does what I want. It works with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, not sure about pdfTeX, I don't use that. it should work with all fonts, too, not only OpenDyslexic, but it seemed fitting. The specific numbers should also be adjusted to the font, geometry…

[image: Result of the above code]