# Letterspacing memoir chapnamefont

Tags: xetex, memoir, chapters, letterspacing

I am using the `companion` chapterstyle within the `memoir` class with XeTeX. To customize the chapter title, I adapted `memoir.cls` slightly:

```
\makechapterstyle{companion}{%
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\Large\MakeTextUppercase}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\raggedleft\chapnamefont \@chapapp}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\fontsize{30}{0}\sffamily}
    \setlength{\chapindent}{\marginparsep}
    \addtolength{\chapindent}{\marginparwidth}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
        \raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1\par\nobreak
    \end{adjustwidth}}}
```

What I get is the following:
[image]

My question is how I can adapt the letterspacing in the word "chapter" so it looks more 'stretched', e.i. like in the following example:

[image]

I have tried to add `\defaultfontfeatures{LetterSpace=50}` in the `\chapnamefont` rule but this doesn't seem to change anything. I have also tried `\lsstyle` from the `microtype` package as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/enlarging-tracking-letter-spacing), but apparently this doesn't work with XeTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a few things differently

1. Call `fontspec` outside `\makechapterstyle`
2. Define explicitly the fonts
3. Use `\addfontfeatures`.

Here's the code; of course the value 200 is exaggerated, I used it to emphasize the result.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{companion}{%
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
      \normalfont\sffamily\bfseries
      \addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=200}% exaggerated
      \Large\MakeTextUppercase
    }
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\raggedleft\chapnamefont \@chapapp}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\fontsize{30}{0}\sffamily}
    \setlength{\chapindent}{\marginparsep}
    \addtolength{\chapindent}{\marginparwidth}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
        \raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1\par\nobreak
    \end{adjustwidth}}}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{companion}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{This is a long chapter title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't follow steps 1 and 2 earlier because I tried to adapt the `memoir.cls`-file itself, but now I just putted all this in the preamble of my actual `tex`-file and it works perfectly.