# Roman numerals not close enough together

Tags: roman-numerals

Instead of 'III' (three 'I's), I want the numbers to look more like those in the attached image.  When using Computer Modern font, is it possible to just remove the horizontal space between letters?  a previous post worked around this by defining a new command using /makebox, but some of the dimensions used absolute length units and therefore is not a solution for different fonts, especially when you want to use this in subscripts or superscripts.

[image]

Comment: Which font are you using?

Comment: To get that sort of effect easily, you will need a typeface that has roman numerals correctly spaced. The only freely available typeface that has them (that I know of though there may well be others) is the Brill typeface available at http://www.brill.com/about/brill-typeface/brill-fonts-end-user-license-agreement.

Comment: the font you show is a "condensed" font -- letters are much narrower than the usual "book" type.  even applying negative letterspacing, the result will not be quite comparable to what you are showing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a negative space between two characters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\joinR}{\hspace{-.1em}}
\newcommand{\RomanI}{I}
\newcommand{\RomanII}{\mbox{\RomanI\joinR\RomanI}}
\newcommand{\RomanIII}{\mbox{\RomanI\joinR\RomanII}}
\newcommand{\RomanIV}{\mbox{\RomanI\joinR\RomanV}}
\newcommand{\RomanV}{V}
\newcommand{\RomanVI}{\mbox{\RomanV\joinR\RomanI}}
\newcommand{\RomanVII}{\mbox{\RomanV\joinR\RomanII}}
\newcommand{\RomanVIII}{\mbox{\RomanV\joinR\RomanIII}}
\newcommand{\RomanIX}{\mbox{\RomanI\joinR\RomanX}}
\newcommand{\RomanX}{X}

\begin{document}

I \RomanI

II \RomanII

III \RomanIII

IV \RomanIV

V \RomanV

VI \RomanVI

VII \RomanVII

VIII \RomanVIII

IX \RomanIX

X \RomanX

\end{document}
```

The above should work with all font switches (`\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, ..., `\Huge`). You can adjust the spacing as needed, if you want them closer together/further apart.

---

[`microtype`](//ctan.org/pkg/microtype)'s `letterspace` package also provides `\textls` that you can use (the starred version):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letterspace}

\newcommand{\ROMAN}{\textls*[-100]}

\begin{document}

I \ROMAN{I}

II \ROMAN{II}

III \ROMAN{III}

IV \ROMAN{IV}

V \ROMAN{V}

VI \ROMAN{VI}

VII \ROMAN{VII}

VIII \ROMAN{VIII}

IX \ROMAN{IX}

X \ROMAN{X}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following defines two macros. The first is `\tighten` which reduces the
space between every letter of its argument by a given length (by default
0.25ex). This is intended for manual insertion of roman numerals.

The second is `\TightRoman` which uses `\tighten` to set a counter with
tightened Roman numbers.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newlength\tighten@stretch
\newcommand*\tighten[2][0.25ex]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax% detect empty argument
  \else
    \bgroup
      \tighten@stretch=#1
      \expandafter\tighten@#2@%
    \egroup
  \fi}
\def\tighten@#1#2{%
  #1%
  \tighten@check{#2}{%
    \kern-\tighten@stretch
    \tighten@#2
  }}
\def\tighten@check#1{%
  \ifx @#1%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi}
\newcommand*\TightRoman[2][0.25ex]{%
  \edef\TightRoman@tmp{\Roman{#2}}%
  \expandafter\TightRoman@i\expandafter{\TightRoman@tmp}{#1}}%
\newcommand*\TightRoman@i[2]{%
  \tighten[#2]{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\newcounter{mycounter}%
\loop\ifnum\value{mycounter}<20
\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\TightRoman{mycounter}\space
\repeat

\tighten{XII}
\end{document}
```

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this post solved my problem: [Enlarging tracking (= letter spacing)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/enlarging-tracking-letter-spacing)

```
\usepackage[letterspace=-150]{microtype}

\textls{III}
```

gives the desired results.