# Modify letterspacing in \chapter, \section etc

Tags: letterspacing, sectsty

I try to create a design similar to this one:

[image]

As you can see, the space between each letter is a bit longer than by default, which is great when typesetting something in capitals. I saw the following topics: [Enlarging tracking (= letter spacing)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62346/enlarging-tracking-letter-spacing) but I was not able to adapt it with my document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Create a new command, \addspaces, ta receive a string and format it as                                                 
% all uppecase with more spaces between letters.                                                                    
\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{2\LocalLetterSpace}                      
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
\setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}                                             
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
    \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax                
}                                                                                                                       
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
    #1%
    \ifx\relax#2\else                         
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%               
    \fi
}     

\newcommand{\addspaces}[1]{
    \textsc{\large\spaceout[2pt]{#1}}
}

\sectionfont{\normalfont\LARGE\scshape\color{red}\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\section{†est}
\addspaces{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: The options `\sffamily` and `\scshape` are bound to conflict unless you happen to employ a sans-serif font that provides small-caps. Is that the case for your document?

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you need a chapter for a mere four sentences? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\addfontfeatures`, which however needs to declare fonts explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont={* Caps},
]

\newcommand{\spacedsc}{\scshape\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=20}}

\sectionfont{\normalfont\LARGE\spacedsc\color{red!80!blue}\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\section{Special Relativity in Four Sentences}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Under pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, you could load the `letterspace` package and add `\lsstyle` to the list of parameters set by `\sectionfont`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty,xcolor}
\usepackage{letterspace}  % for "\lsstyle" macro

\sectionfont{\normalfont\LARGE\scshape\lsstyle\color{red}\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\section{Special Relativity in Four Sentences}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that I use XeLaTex. If that help, I don't need the sf font.

Comment: @Nakrule - Indeed, the fact that you use XeLaTeX is absolutely crucial here. Unfortunately, letterspacing is not available under XeLaTeX -- at least not with the `letterspace` package or its big brother, the `microtype` package. I'm not aware of any other packages that provide letterspacing under XeLaTeX.

Comment: In my document, I use a custom macro named `addspaces{some text}` to do add more spaces between letters and put everything in capitals. Before posting here, I tried to use it in my `\sectionfont` without any success, but maybe it is still possible to find a way with it ?

Comment: In your MWE you define `\addspaces` but you don't use it. Please show how you used it and say what the problem was. Might it have anything to do with the section title appearing in the ToC?