# Adjust letterspace of two or three lines in middle of the paragraph in lualatex

Tags: luatex

How to adjust the variable letter space of the lines in a paragraph through lualatex

For example:

Para para para para
\letterspace{2}{Para para para para
Para para para para}
Para para para para

Para para para para
\letterspace{5}{Para para para para
Para para para para}
Para para para para

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: See [Enlarging tracking (= letter spacing)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62346/316068).

Comment: The question is understandable, but it needs more code here.